# What does Any mean in this context? Why does adding `:Any` get rid of the compiler error?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I was trying out some example code from https://github.com/dkandalov/kotlin-99#lists. First there is a function that takes a list of any type and returns a list of lists

```
fun <T> pack(list: List<T>):List<List<T>> =
   if (list.isEmpty()) emptyList()
   else{
      val packed = list.takeWhile { it==list.first() }
      listOf(packed) + pack(list.drop(packed.size))
   }
```

It takes a list like [1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5] and returns [[1,1,1],[3],[4],[5,5,5]], i.e., it groups runs of integers.

Now I wrote a function that takes this an run length encodes it. My function would return for the above example `[Pair(1,3),3,4,Pair(5,3)]`. I wrote the following function

```
fun <T> runLength2(list: List<T>): List<Any> =
   pack(list).map { it -> if(it.size>1) it[0] to it.size else it[0]}
```

but it leads to a type inference error

> Type inference failed. Required List < Any > , found List< Any? >

for the return type.

If I insert `:Any`like so, the problem is solved.

```
fun <T:Any> runLength2(list: List<T>): List<Any> =
   pack(list).map { it -> if(it.size>1) it[0] to it.size else it[0]}
```

I am new to Kotlin. Could someone explain why adding Any solves the problem and what creates the problem in the first place?

Comment: Nullability issue. `Any` is a superclass of all classes in Kotlin but you also have to specify that your input list does not contain null objects otherwise it will infer it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about nullability.

In Kotlin, the top type is `Any?`, which can hold any object or `null`.  The subtype `Any`, however, is not nullable, and can't store a null.

In your first version, the generic type `T` could be any type; in particular, it could be a nullable type.  So the compiler won't let you return a `T` as `Any`, in case it's null.

You could solve this by declaring it to return `Any?`, or by restricting the generic type to be non-nullable.  In your second version, you've done the latter by restricting `T` to be the non-nullable `Any` type.

Comment: @Arun You're very welcome; I'm pleased it helped!  By the way, I should perhaps have pointed out that the first option — returning `Any?` — is probably preferable, as it allows the function to be used more widely.  But both options work fine.  Kotlin's very precise about where nulls are and aren't possible; it can seem very fussy if you're not used to it, but it prevents several big classes of error, and makes it easier to see what's going on, especially for function parameters and results.